# Why some operations on tensors don't give a tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, multilinear-algebra

The gradient is a tensor $\nabla f:\mathbf{V} \to \mathbf{R}$ where the partial derivatives are evaluated at some point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$. And evaluation of this linear form at some vector $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ gives

$$
(\nabla f)(\mathbf{v}) = \partial_x f v_1 + \partial_y f v_2 + \partial_z f v_3
$$
Furthermore in going to a new coordinate system these partial derivatives transform in the expected way.

But what about a function $g:\mathbf{V} \to \mathbf{R}$ which is defined only using the partial derivative of $f$ in the $x$ direction.
$$
g(\mathbf{v}) = \partial_x f v_1 + \partial_x f v_2 + \partial_x f v_3
$$
As I understand this is not considered a tensor because in moving to a new coordinate system it does not transform correctly.

This has confused me endlessly. The strict definition considers a map such as $f:\mathbf{V} \to \mathbf{R}$ a tensor if linearity holds in each parameter. The function $g$ above certainly satisfies that. It seems to me that this definition is not used and that the definition of a tensor that is actually used consists of two parts.

- linearity in each parameter (i.e. multilinear form),
- and the algebraic structure of the coefficients is maintained in coordinate transformation

Because once we have calculated $\partial_x f$ it is just a scalar and we just hit $(\partial_x f,\partial_x f,\partial_x f)$ with the usual transformation for a covariant vector to get the new coefficients for $g$ in the new coordinate system. That these new coefficients don't have the right algebraic structure doesn't make multilinearity of $g$ go away. Is this at all correct?

Comment: No i think its not correct. Look at this: $g(x,\lambda y,z) \ne \lambda g(x,y,z)$

Comment: @crush3dice This is irrelevant, it only needs to be linear in $v_1,v_2,v_3$. (Which it is.)

Comment: It baffled me too in the past. Will leave it to more knowledgeable people to answer, but I wouldn't be too surprised that the confusion arises because the words "is (not) a tensor" are used in two different meanings. For every choice of co-ordinates, your formula produces a tensor. However, when the co-ordinates change, the formula produces a *different* tensor. Thus, the formula *itself* "is not a tensor", in the sense that the result of the formula is not a well-defined, single, independent of co-ordinates, tensor, but rather a different tensor for each choice of co-ordinates.

Comment: oh i somehow read that wrong. Then my comment is ofcourse irrelevant.

Comment: I dont quite get your definition of a tensor then... $df$ is a 1-form, $\partial_x$ is a differntial-operator and $\partial_x \otimes df = g$ is a tensor.
One can show that every multilienar map is a tensor actually. 

My guess is that for some reason you want to rotate the $x,y,z$. But that would also change $g$ and then you get something different while in the first case if you rotate $x,y,z$ because of symmetry it stays the same. But again, if you rotate the $x$ inside your differential-operator $\partial_x$ i dont understand what you understand as a tensor.

Comment: @StinkingBishop That is actually an excellent way of thinking about the issue.

Comment: Also, again will leave it to more knowledgeable people to answer, but you can also define tensors on *manifolds* and in that case (unlike $\mathbb R^3$) not all of the manifold may be represented by the same coordinate system. (E.g. on the sphere you may need one map to co-ordinates for everything but the South pole, and another map to co-ordinates for everything but the North pole.)

Comment: (Cont'd) In that case, you can still define a tensor the way you did it - using an arbitrary formula on any one map, but then you need to make sure your formulas match on the intersection. If they don't, then again it can be said "it is not a tensor" - with the meaning "it doesn't well define a tensor".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fundamental thing to remember about vectors and their basis dependent representations is that the basis is arbitrary. Anyone has the right to express any vector in a vector space in terms of any basis of their choosing. When expressed in a basis, a vector looks like an $n$-tuple of scalars, but unless it comes with that promise of that change of basis formula, an arbitrary $n$-tuple of scalars does not actual define a vector.

A tensor is the same except now the promise has to be that the change of basis formula involves multiple factors of the change of basis matrix.

The mathematician's preferred way of achieving that is to give coordinate-free definitions of things like vector spaces and tensors built out of them. But it's fine to think of vectors and tensors by their coordinate components too, as long as you remember that you don't actually have vectors and tensors unless they behave right under change of basis.

And that's just vectors and tensors from a vector space. When we consider vector fields and tensor fields on a manifold, instead of arbitrary changes of basis on the tangent space, we consider coordinate changes of the manifold, and that induces a change of basis in the tangent space and tensors out of the tangent space. Tensors are different than tensor fields, but for brevity people often call them tensors too, so let's address both.

---

In linear algebra, you can make tensors out of a vector space $V$, a tensor of type $(p,q)$ is an element of the tensor product of $p$-many of copies of $V$ and $q$-many of its dual space $V^*$. In your case, a map $V\to \mathbb{R}$ is a tensor of rank $(0,1)$, also known as a linear functional or dual vector on $V$. If you wanted to, for some fixed function $f(x,y,z)$ and some coordinates $(a,b,c)$, you could compute the derivatives and evaluate at those coordinates and get numbers $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b,c),\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b,c),\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(a,b,c)$. You could then assemble them into a triple $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b,c),\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b,c),\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(a,b,c)\right)$ and declare it to be a linear functional on your vector space.

Since your function $f$ and your coordinates $(a,b,c)$ had nothing to do with your vector space, you can declare its components to be this in one basis. If someone wants to know what they are in another basis, simply apply the change of basis matrix. Thus $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b,c),\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b,c),\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(a,b,c)$ is a valid linear functional on your three dimensional vector space. It is a tensor of type $(0,1).$

It doesn't especially matter how you chose the components of your tensor in your starting basis, so you could just as well have chosen three different numbers, including $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b,c),\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b,c),\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b,c)\right).$ That is also a valid tensor of type $(0,1).$

So to sum up, as far as the linear algebra of just a single vector space is concerned, both $(\partial_xf,\partial_yf,\partial_zf)$ and $(\partial_xf,\partial_xf,\partial_xf)$ are tensors.

The issue will come when we try to consider them tensor fields on a manifold.

---

In differential geometry, you do the same thing, you make tensors out of a vector space. Except now the vector space is the tangent space of a manifold $M$. And it varies from point to point. A tensor is an element of the tensor product of some number of copies of the tangent space $T_xM$ to a point $x$ and some number of copies of the cotangent space $T_xM^*$.

To make a *tensor field* on the manifold, we must choose a tensor from the tensor product of the tangent space *at each point* of the manifold.

A smooth manifold is something which locally looks like $\mathbb{R}^n$, so it admits local coordinates. Expressed in those local coordinates, a tensor of type $(p,q)$ is an array of $n^pn^q$ functions on $M$. But we may choose different coordinates around any point, and we have the right to express our tensors in any coordinates. Changing coordinates also changes the basis of the tangent space and its dual space. So it's like the change of basis operation in linear algebra, as well as a change of coordinates in the coordinate functions at the same time.

This is a constraint on what a tensor can look like. The change of basis has to match the change of coordinates. You can't swap the two basis vectors without also swapping the two coordinates. If you change the coordinates by a function, then the basis for the tangent space changes by the jacobian of that function.

So this is why $(\partial_xf,\partial_xf,\partial_xf)$ is not a tensor in the sense of differential geometry. When you change coordinates, a tensor should transform the $z$-component by the $z$-partial derivative of the change of coordinate function. But your object scales every component by the $x$-derivative.

It's also why the Christoffel symbols are not a tensor. As the derivative of a tensor, they change with an additional term, rather than a pure change of basis matrix, which is required for tensors. The easiest way to see that is that a tensor which is zero in one coordinate system must be zero in every coordinate system, which the Christoffel symbols do not safisty.

There is a theorem that an array of smooth functions is a tensor if they are $C^\infty(M)$ linear, when viewed as a function on vector fields. The Christoffel symbols also fail that test.

Comment: So what is wrong with using $(\partial_xf,\partial_xf,\partial_xf)$ to pick out an arbitrary three numbers that make up a dual vector at each point of $M$ this gives a tensor field right? Of course in a new coordinate system the coefficients won't resemble anything like $partial_xf$.

Comment: When someone says that is not a tensor is this a terminology issue? They don't mean the above is impossible but mean if we want a tensor with coefficients $(\partial_xf,\partial_xf,\partial_xf)$ in every coordinate system with $x$ being the first parameter that is impossible. And likewise "Christoffel symbols are not a tensor" is saying while we can define a tensor agreeing with the Christoffel symbols in one coordinate system we can't define it to agree across all coordinate systems and that part is implied in the phrase "Christoffel symbols are not a tensor"?

Comment: @ user782220: I think you have that right.  (As an aside, for discussions, it might be helpful to notionally distinguish between the tensor field $(\partial_x, \partial_y, \partial_z)(x,y,z)$ on the one hand, and the tensor $(\partial_x(a,b,c), \partial_y(a,b,c), \partial_z(a,b,c))$ at a fixed point $(a,b,c)$.)

Comment: Succinctly, the phrase "the Christoffel symbols are not a tensor" is an abbreviation for: "There exists no tensor field whose coordinate expression in **every** coordinate system is the array of Christoffel symbols in that coordinate system."

Comment: @user782220 "So what is wrong with using..." a tensor exists irrespective of any coordinate expression. That fact requires the coordinate expansions in different coordinates to be related in a strict way in terms of the change of coordinate function. This object does not meet the requirement. I will edit my answer to make clearer this aspect

Comment: @JesseMadnick good suggestion about the notation

Comment: @JesseMadnick It seems to me books start by defining tensors as these coordinate independent object but then start speaking of these things like Christoffel symbols as not tensors while defining them a coordinate dependent way instead of defining them in a coordinate independent way that happens to not be an tensor. And they are rather imprecise about defining the phrase "the Christoffel symbols are not a tensor" and this causes confusion.

Comment: @user782220: Yes, many books do that -- especially older books and those geared towards physicists -- though certainly not all of them.  In particular, books aimed at pure math graduate students (or upper-year math undergraduates) often work in coordinate-free terms, so this sort of confusion won't arise (or even be addressed, really).

Comment: @JesseMadnick Wait after reading more about the Christoffel symbols how is it even possible to define them in a coordinate free way. Which books are you talking about?

Comment: @user782220: Sorry, I should be clearer.  The Christoffel symbols are (essentially) the coordinate expressions of a "covariant derivative operator" (a.k.a. a "connection on a vector bundle"), which can certainly be defined without reference to coordinates.  I am thinking of John Lee's book "Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds" and Manfredo do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry."

Comment: @user782220 sorry it took a minute but i expanded the first part, explaining about why things have to depend on choice of basis in a fixed way. thanks for the accept and bounty!

Answer (score 2):

First of all if we have a function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R$, where let's say $\Omega$ is a domain in $\mathbb R^3$, then $\nabla f(p)$ is a vector field
$$\Omega\to\mathbb R^3$$
which assign an arrow $\nabla f(p)$ at $p$. But also
a map $\Omega\to L(\mathbb R^3,\mathbb R)$
which  assigns to each $p$ in $\Omega$ a linear map
$\nabla f(p):\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ given by
$$\nabla f(p)\cdot \mathbf v=\mathbf v^1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p)+
\mathbf v^2\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p)+
\mathbf v^3\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(p),
$$
and can be understood of how $f$ varies in the direction $\mathbf v$ at $p$.

Second, now suppose that we have a change of coordinates $\Phi:\Gamma\to\Omega$, which is a differentiable map with derivative $J\Phi$ of rank three everywhere at $\Gamma\subseteq\mathbb R^3$, where we have $\Phi(q)=p$ for a unique $q$ in
$\Gamma$.

So $f\circ\Phi:\Gamma\to\mathbb R$ (is differentiable if $f$ is)
and by the chain's rule
$\nabla(f\circ\Phi)=\nabla f\cdot J\Phi$
through $\Gamma$,  and at $q$
$$\nabla(f\circ\Phi)(q)=\nabla f(p)\cdot J\Phi(q).$$

If we think that $\Phi:(u,v,w)^{\top}\mapsto(x,y,z)^{\top}$ is the
dependence of the old coordinates into the new ones,
then

$$\left[
\frac{\partial f\circ\Phi}{\partial u}(q)\quad
\frac{\partial f\circ\Phi}{\partial v}(q)\quad
\frac{\partial f\circ\Phi}{\partial w}(q)\right]
=$$
$$
\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p)\quad
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p)\quad
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(p)
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u}(q)&\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v}(q)&\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial w}(q)\\
\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u}(q)&\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v}(q)&\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial w}(q)\\
\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}(q)&\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}(q)&\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial w}(q)\\
\end{array}
\right],
$$
which means that
$$\frac{\partial f\circ\Phi}{\partial u}(q)=
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p)\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}(q)+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p)\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}(q)+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(p)\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}(q),
$$
$$\frac{\partial f\circ\Phi}{\partial v}(q)=
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p)\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}(q)+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p)\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}(q)+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(p)\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}(q),
$$
and
$$\frac{\partial f\circ\Phi}{\partial w}(q)=
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p)\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}(q)+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p)\frac{\partial y}{\partial w}(q)+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(p)\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}(q),
$$
are the components of $\nabla(f\circ\Phi)$ at $q$ (who controls what happen at $p$
with the new coordinates). So, $\nabla f$ is a **rank one tensor**.

Third, for maps $\mathbf V\times\mathbf V\to\mathbb R$ which comply something similar, would be
dubbed **rank two tensors**, case that is not present in the gradient operation.

Comment: @user78220. Your $g$ is linear but under a change of coordinates  $\Phi$ you can see that $g\circ\Phi$ is not necessarily linear, safe in case that  $\Phi$ is a linear coordinates change. Then $g$ is not a rank one tensor, meanwhile $\nabla f$ at  $p$ in the new coordinates change changes to $\nabla (f\circ\Phi)(p)J\Phi(q)$  which is a composition of linear maps, giving to $\nabla f$ the category of rank one tensor. Please tell us if this commentary helps. Greets.